# Multi floating button in coordinatorlayout in accordance with a bottom view's visibility

Tags: view, visibility, android-coordinatorlayout, floating-action-button

I have a big problem to position 3 floating buttons in a coordinatorlayout. The problem came from 3 other views, which could be visible or gone.

On the previous screens, you can see 3 possibilities: with or without DEUS view, and with a progressbar (it's possible to have DEUS view + progressbar too).

Finally, the floating are position as if there are both progressbar and deus view, but do not move is these views disappear or not.

I've tried lots of cases:
- anchor with the deus view did not work if deus is gone, floating went to the top left corner.
- without anchor works a little but it's not reactive with layout change.

So could you help me, I don't understand why with anchor, it works for example with a snackbar, but not in my case.

Here's the layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <fragment xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/google_map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lyt_floating_buttons"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_anchor="@+id/frameLayout_deus"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="top|end"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/normal_spacing"
            android:layout_marginBottom="186dp"
            app:useCompatPadding="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/fab_add_find"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/normal_spacing"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/normal_spacing"
                android:onClick="clickAddHandleFinders"
                android:src="@drawable/finds_plus"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/black_xp" />

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/fab_target_recentrer"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/normal_spacing"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/normal_spacing"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:onClick="clickCenterMap"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_gps_fixed_white_24dp"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/black_xp" />

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/fab_map"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/normal_spacing"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/normal_spacing"
                android:onClick="clickChangeMap"
                android:src="@drawable/map_blanc"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/black_xp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/frameLayout_deus"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginBottom="130dp"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_view_deus"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/normal_spacing"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/normal_spacing"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:drawablePadding="@dimen/normal_spacing"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/picto_deus_deconnected_red"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/deus_not_connected"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_target"
                android:layout_width="24dp"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/normal_spacing"
                android:onClick="goTargetsId"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_bullseye" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_gear"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16sp"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/normal_spacing"
                android:onClick="goDeusSettings"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_settings_gears" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <include
            android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
            layout="@layout/xprunning_bottom_sheet"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And the code to manage that (it's kotlin):

```
private fun initView() {
    val deusParam = binding.frameLayoutDeus.layoutParams as CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams

    // Gère le slider
    if (xpUser.mapTypeSecondary != null) {
        deusParam.bottomMargin = (144 * density).toInt()
    } else {
        deusParam.bottomMargin = (96 * density).toInt()
    }

    if (!isDeusConnectionEnable()) {
        fab_add_find.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        deusParam.height = 0
    } else {
        fab_add_find.visibility = View.GONE
        deusParam.height = (48 * density).toInt()
    }

    binding.frameLayoutDeus.layoutParams = deusParam
    initPeekView()
}

private fun initPeekView() {
    if (xpUser.mapTypeSecondary != null) {
        layout_ign.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        bottomSheetBehavior!!.peekHeight = (144 * density).toInt()
    } else {
        layout_ign.visibility = View.GONE
        bottomSheetBehavior?.peekHeight = (96 * density).toInt()
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]